# What would be the difference if I use "never once" with perfect aspect sentences?

Tags: present-perfect, present-simple, aspect, emphasis

Suppose:

- I have never treated her like that.

I know I can put more emphasis by saying

- I never once treated her like that.

I am thinking of this sentence in perfect aspect. I am wondering what would be the idiomatic usage in the present perfect aspect. I mean, when would someone say this instead of the past simple variant?

> I've never once treated her like that.

Is there any specific case for which we'd better to use the perfect aspect?

Answer (score 3):

I would tend to use your third case when there is a continuing relationship with "her", so the occasions (or possibilities) of treating her in any particular way continue to the present (and beyond).

If the relationship no longer exists, I would be more likely to use the simple past.

But, as usual, the choice of perfect or non-perfect is about how the speaker is choosing to portray the temporal relationships, not about an objective difference; so I could use the simple past even if the relationship is continuing - perhaps conveying that I see occasions on which I might have treated her like that as being finished. I could even use the perfect when the relationship is no longer current, if I am seeing this as part of my own continuing behaviour up to the present.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!